# Dynamic weekday border color [React-Calendar]

Tags: css, reactjs, react-calendar

I want to add dynamic color to border of each weekday in react-calendar.
And want to change text on hover on each date.

Sample Image:

[image: Sample Image]

I tried adding onMouseEnter event using tileContent props

```
tileContent={({date})=>(
  <div onMouseEnter={(e)=>{setHoverText("hello")}}/>)}
```